# How to $group conditionally with aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I'm currently trying to work out how I can create a group for certain objects in an array. For example, based off the document structure below, I'd like to create a `$group` where only people with an `id` of 5 and 4 are processed into the group.

What I'm trying to achieve in pseudo code:

```
        { $unwind:"$people" },

        { $group: {
            if("$people.id"===5 || "$people.id"===4){
                  _id: $people.id
                  averageScore: {$avg: "$score"}
            }
        }}
```

This would return two documents, one with the `_id` of 5 and an `averageScore` of 10 and one with `_id` 4 and an `averageScore` of 13.5

Sample Document Structure:

**doc 1**

```
{
    gameId:394028,
    people: [{
      id: 5,
      score: 10,
      mapSide: 'left'
   },{
      id: 4,
      score: 14,
      mapSide: 'right'
   },{
      id: 1,
      score: 11,
      mapSide: 'right'
   },{
      id: 2,
      score: 12,
      mapSide: 'left'
   }]
}
```

**doc 2**

```
{
    gameId:394028,
    people: [{
      id: 7,
      score: 5,
      mapSide: 'left'
   },{
      id: 9,
      score: 10,
      mapSide: 'right'
   },{
      id: 4,
      score: 13,
      mapSide: 'right'
   },{
      id: 1,
      score: 12
      mapSide: 'left'
   }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to go with something like

```
{ $unwind:"$people" },
{ $match:{$or :[{'people.id' : 4}, {'people.id' :5}]} },
{ $group: {_id:"$people.id"
           averageScore: {$avg: "$score"}}
```

`$match` will basically filter your unwound collection like a find command (takes the same syntax) and passes the matched documents to the next stage. You could replace the `$or` with `'people.id':{$in:[4,5]}` if you have a lot of ids to match.

---

**Edit:** Detailed explanation of this pipeline after comment:

What happens in the first two pipeline stages to doc1 from the question is this:

- `{ $unwind:"$people" }` 
  results:

  ```
  {gameId:394028, people: {id: 5, score: 10, mapSide: 'left'}},
  {gameId:394028, people: {id: 4, score: 14, mapSide: 'right'}},
  {gameId:394028, people: {id: 1, score: 11, mapSide: 'right'}},
  {gameId:394028, people: {id: 2, score: 12, mapSide: 'left' }},
  ```
- `{ $match:{$or :[{'people.id' : 4}, {'people.id' :5}]} }` results:

  ```
  {gameId:394028, people: {id: 5, score: 10, mapSide: 'left'}},
  {gameId:394028, people: {id: 4, score: 14, mapSide: 'right'}},
  ```

After that you still have access to all fields that where available in the original document in the `$group` stage.

Comment: Hey this worked perfectly, I have a question though for my own understanding - I can still access the gameId from the $group pipe (which is what I wanted as I have other information like gameDuration etc.) What I'm curious about is how I still have access to that information if it was (I'm assuming) removed during the $match pipe.  As in I'd assume I could only access information from the 'people collection' that was matched, but I can still access outside information. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @Joel added the details of the first two stages to the answer as an explanation hope that helps

Comment: @Trubert Thank you very much, that clarified it perfectly.